# Combile External JS files using W3 Total Cache

Tags: cache, plugin-w3-total-cache

Is there any option or is it recommended to combine external JS files using W3 Total Cache plugin for wordpress. When I say exxternal JS files, I mean that I want to combine .JS files that on other domains/CDNs, like the .JS for facebook like button, Google+1 ,etc. I want them to be combined using w3 total cache. Is it possible?

Answer (score 2):

It would be a bad idea to combine common CDN served files that the majority of web users already have cached for obvious reasons...

Comment: I totally agree, this is a bad idea, it goes against the main reason why it is external...